# Duplicated cells skip 10 rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with two sheets, `Sheet 1` contains some text and formulas I wish to duplicate down to write 2,000 odd lines of C# code for my project. Extremely repetitive, so I thought I could use Excel to write it for me. `Sheet 2` contains an extract from my database which I wish to use to populate that values with. My section of Excel code looks like this and is spread out over 10 rows and 5 columns:

```
new AccountingPeriod()              
    {           
        MonthCovered="=Sheet2!B2",
        StartDate=DateTime.Parse("Sheet2!C2"),
        EndDate=DateTime.Parse("Sheet2!D2"),
        AccountingPeriodDescription="Sheet2!E2",
        Active='=Sheet2!F2',
        April='=Sheet2!G2,
        TaxYear="Sheet2!H2"
    },
```

When I highlight these 10 rows and use the Excel duplicate tool I want the cell references (for example, in my spreadsheet `Sheet1!D3 = Sheet2!B2`, I want `Sheet1!D13 = Sheet2!B3 NOT Sheet2!B13`) to increment by 1, not 10 as it's doing in my spreadsheet.

We have tried an alternative solution of writing a macro to insert 10 blank rows in `Sheet2` for every populated row so that the duplicated references are correct in `Sheet1` but we're currently failing miserably at getting that to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a direct reference that is going to change on a 1-to-1 with the copy, use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) with a little maths to achieve the 10-to-1 row stagger.

In Sheet1!D3 this references Sheet2!B2.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,INT(ROW(1:1)/10)+2)
```

In Sheet1!D13 this references Sheet2!B3.

The [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) can accomplish the same thing but it is a volatile function that recalculates whenever anything in the workbook changes. INDEX provides the same functionality while remaining non-volatile and will only recalculate when something that affects its returned value changes.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeeped! Solved my problem straight away and a very helpful explanation of INDEX.