# Drag a formula down with Row changes by another interval other than one

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to figure this out for hours now. I have this formula:

```
 =PROMEDIO.SI.CONJUNTO(Flankers!C15:C54;Flankers!D15:D54;1)
```

I have done this one manually. I have my data in the Flankers sheet and now I'm calculating the means for my reaction times and my accuracy scores on a second sheet. The data for each participant is the same (93 rows per participant) and what I am trying to do is to drag this formula down to fill in each participant automatically (I have my 29 participants in a column). Of course, each reference changes only by 1 number. For example, I have the formula in C2, so when I drag it down to C3, the formula changes to

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Flankers!C16:C55;Flankers!D16:D55;1)
```

I need all of the rows to go up by 93 and keep the range the same (40 cells), so that C3's cell should be =AVERAGEIFS(Flankers!C108:C147;Flankers!D108:D147;1) and then C4's cell should be

```
 =AVERAGEIFS(Flankers!C201:C240;Flankers!D201:D240;1)
```

, etc. Manually this is very tedious (2698 rows in total). Can someone shed light on this and explain it to where I could modify it for future analyses?

Comment: Sorry, I'm working with a Spanish Excel interface.. PROMEDIO.SI.CONJUNTO() is the same as AVERAGEIFS(). Thought I caught them all before I uploaded the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost marked this as a duplicate of [Duplicated cells skip 10 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33803834/duplicated-cells-skip-10-rows/33804279#33804279) but in fact it is the reverse of it. However, the solution is the same. Use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) with a little maths to achieve the stagger.

The easiest way to do this is with the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) but that function is considered volatile¹ and will recalulate whenever anything in the workbook changes. Large numbers of these will result in calculation lag everytime something is typed into any cell.

With the volatile¹ [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592),

```
=AVERAGEIFS(OFFSET(Flankers!$C$15, (ROW(1:1)-1)*93, 0, 40, 1),
            OFFSET(Flankers!$C$15, (ROW(1:1)-1)*93, 1, 40, 1), 1)
```

With the non-volatile [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a),

```
=AVERAGEIFS(INDEX(Flankers!C:C, 15+(ROW(1:1)-1)*93):INDEX(Flankers!C:C, 54+(ROW(1:1)-1)*93),
            INDEX(Flankers!D:D, 15+(ROW(1:1)-1)*93):INDEX(Flankers!D:D, 54+(ROW(1:1)-1)*93), 1)
```

The second formula may look more complicated but all it really does is provide a starting cell and and ending cell for each range in the [AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690). INDEX references the entire column and some basic maths do the rest.

In ES-ES formula language (with semicolon list separators) as,

```
=PROMEDIO.SI.CONJUNTO(DESREF(Flankers!$C$15; (FILA(1:1)-1)*93; 0; 40; 1);
                      DESREF(Flankers!$C$15; (FILA(1:1)-1)*93; 1; 40; 1); 1)

=PROMEDIO.SI.CONJUNTO(INDICE(Flankers!C:C; 15+(FILA(1:1)-1)*93):INDICE(Flankers!C:C; 54+(FILA(1:1)-1)*93);
                      INDICE(Flankers!D:D; 15+(FILA(1:1)-1)*93):INDICE(Flankers!D:D; 54+(FILA(1:1)-1)*93); 1)
```

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: It seems so perfect!! I was so close to doing this myself. I've copied what you've done and now it's giving me the "We found a problem with this formula." Am I missing something? I feel like it should work!

Comment: sorry Robbie - I go tied up with publishing the post and forgot to translate it. **AVERAGEIFS** should be **PROMEDIO.SI.CONJUNTO**, **INDEX** should be **INDICE** and all commas should be semicolons; e,g, `, ► ;`. I'll modify my answer shortly.

Comment: OK, it's ok. I think the Spanish interface uses semicolons instead of commas. Fixed it! Thank you SO MUCH!!!

Comment: We realized it at the same time! haha... Also, when I do this in the future, Row is always just (1:1)? For example, now my next formula that I want to do this to is in D (as well as two more formulas in E and F). What are the variables that have to change? You are a God-send, thank you!!!

Comment: `ROW(1:1)` (or `FILA(1:1)`) is **1**. Fill down one row and it becomes `ROW(2:2)` which is **2**. Used in the `15+(FILA(1:1)-1)*93` you start at **15** and then get 15, 108, 201, 294, etc. as you fill down. The same goes for the ending position; e.g. 54, 147, 240, 333, etc.